# Configuring pcore in xilinx xps

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I have a vhdl design that is created in Xilinx ISE and I would like to bring it over to the XPS/EDK 14.2 as a pcore. The issue is, I am not really sure how I should be hooking it up. The XPS utility gives me the option of an AXI Burst bus. Am I suppose to create an interface to hook up the AXI signals to my module? I am not really sure how I am suppose to use it as a pcore, since I am new to the XPS tool. I was under the impression the XPS tool would make the appropriate hook ups for me (i.e. ACLK would connect to my clock, etc.).

Any background information would be appreciated. I am only finding tutorials with the older version of XPS and it doesn't really cover my issue.

Comment: Are you using a processor or not? And what do you mean by "XPS utility"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the XPS import peripheral wizard. I have been able to import it into my project, but I am getting many NGBUILD errors that I am trying to fix up.

Comment: Ok that makes it easier to understand, there are some really good guidelines available for this if you search the internet, I have not used the latest version but I used 13.2 and it was much more stable than earlier releases.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into tools like ImpulseC from Impulse Accelerated Technologies?

I have had years of good results using that tool to develop pcores in ANSI-C and them exporting the results into correctly formed Xilinx pcores.

If you asked, I'm sure you could get a demo license to see if it would help in your situation.

It spits everything out in VHDL and you can read through the results to see how to do it.